# How do I convert all the vowels within a string to white-spaces in python

Tags: python

I am trying to take an input string and replace any vowels in it with a whitespace. How do you do this?

```
def w_space (s):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    string = s
    for a in string:
        for b in vowels:
            if string[a] == vowels[b]:
                vowels = ""
    return string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all instead of setting `string = s` simply loop through `s` as it is. Also, instead of looping through both `s` and `vowels` just loop `s` and check if the letter is in `vowels`, if so add a white space to `string` if not add the letter to `string`. Here is the code:

```
def w_space (s):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    string = ""
    for a in s:
        if a in vowels:
            string += " "
        else:
            string += a
    return string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(s):
    l = list(s)
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i] in "aeiouAEIOU":
            l[i] = " "
    return ''.join(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a list comprehension

```
def w_space(s):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    return "".join([" " if x in vowels else x for x in s])
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is an option as well

```
def w_space (s):
    from re import sub, IGNORECASE
    vowels = r'[aeiou]'
    return sub(vowels, ' ', s, flags=IGNORECASE)
```